# XLSX closed for some import preferences?

Tags: excel, adobe-indesign

My goal is to read chosen excel sheet (xlsx file) while importing to InDesign (CS5). To do it I am setting 
app.excelImportPreferences.sheetIndex 
OR
app.excelImportPreferences.sheetName
and both fails -- > first sheet data is imported only.

Can you confirm this properties don't work with XLSX files? 
Tested with XLS and passed.